# Passing function parameters of various types from batch script to a python function in a python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm working with a python script (let's call it MyScript.py) containing a function with many parameters of various types, which I'm not allowed to modify:

```
def MyFunction(str1, int1, str2, str3, int2, bool1):
    #Do something with input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eval(sys.argv[1])
```

And I want to call this function from a batch script with a list of parameters. I tried the ways below but it failed:

```
python -c "import MyScript;MyScript.MyFunction('str1', 'int1', 'str2', 'str3', 'int2', 'bool1')"
python -c "import MyScript;MyScript.MyFunction([str1], [int1], [str2], [str3], [int2], [bool1])"
```

How should I call this function then? And what's the correct way to format the input parameters to a python script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the `python --help`:

```
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
             application. Typical usage is python3 -X importtime -c 'import asyncio'
```

So, when you use the `-c` flag, you are already *running* within python, so there is no need to use the `eval(sys.argv[1])`, you just need to call the function with the parameters (their values):

```sh
python -c "import MyScript;MyScript.MyFunction('str1', 1, 'str2', 'str3', 2, True)"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. It worked.
However as I passed the str1, which is actually a dir, the python system warned that the path syntax is incorrect and is was displayed as 'D:\\folder1\folder2\\folder3\x08uild\\file.txt'
It was originally ''D:\folder1\folder2\folder3\build\file.txt' (some '\' was replaced by '\\', some are not and 'build' was replaced by 'x08uild')
Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: i would try to use the raw string: `r'my\fancy\path'`